# $watch vs curly braces - $watch does not catch change of a variable on scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem in AngularJS. I will try to simplify things to explain the problem I am having.

I have created a directive that should handle image uploading. The flow goes like this.

If the image exists server will return the url of a statically served image. The url and the directive are loaded asynchronously from server so there is no way of telling which one will load first. I pass a variable that I get as an attribute

```
<my-directive vc-current-url="vm.data.profileURL"> </my-directive>
```

Directive scope

```
scope : { "currentURL" : '=vcCurrentUrl' }
```

So, in my template I am able to {{scope.currentURL}} and when it gets loaded - it will show up. But I have to do more things when that url is loaded - pass it to another function (reasons). So fine I will just add a watcher and wait for it to load? But not.

```
scope.$watch(scope.currentURL, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(' changed to ' + newValue + ' from ' + oldValue);
}, true);
```

console.log gets called once and it prints

```
changed to undefined from undefined
```

What am I missing?

Oh and I'm using Angular 1.5.

EDIT 
Couple of answers were that I did not watch the correct variable. The code below does not work and it throws

```
Error: currentURL is not defined
```

Code:

```
scope.$watch('currentURL', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(' changed to ' + newValue + ' from ' + oldValue);
});
```

Comment: Console.log will execute immediately and not wait for any other code, which is where your undefineds are coming from, just FYI.

Comment: No. Why would it execute immediately? It is placed *inside* callback function that should be called when the variable changed. And for that matter console log is called at the same moment when the braces would pick up the change and print them to view

Comment: You can try and wrap the `watch` inside a `$timeout` and it will run after the DOM is rendered. It might help

Comment: Likewise change your code to `if(!angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)){
console.log(' changed to ' + newValue + ' from ' + oldValue);}` and see what it prints. As it will only log if your value changes.

Comment: @AlonEitan In $timeout? that might help, I will try.

Comment: @KreepN well ok, no problems to  do that but when i see that the change is happening. There is no point in filtering things when I have nothing to filter.

Comment: perhaps the problem is that currentURL is undefined or is not passed correctly to the directive's scope. Can you add jsfiddle example?

Comment: Also, I know I deleted my answer, but if `{{scope.currentURL}}` is working, then try `scope.$watch('scope.currentURL', ...` (It's different from what I previously suggested)

Comment: I'm sure it's something simple really, I think the reason people are mentioning the watch being incorrect is due to the declaration: `"currentURL" : '=vcCurrentUrl'` as I've always seen it as `currentURL : '=vcCurrentUrl'`.

Comment: @KreepN idk, i wanted it to be a valid JSON... maybe my osd screwed me.  I will update you

Comment: You might also benefit by posting the directive here, so we can see if you're using any special syntax like `controllerAs` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was wrong.

Austn and Alon were right but I failed to notice that they had apostrophes around the variable name and I do not have them.

Following the conversation I tried to put my watcher function in $timeout. The variable loaded in next cycle and I got some weird parse message (that url.com/variable.jpg is not a valid var name).

So at that point I realized that if you don't put var name inside apostrophes it will use the var value (or undefined).

So why did I get that console log and what I did was actually

```
$watch(undefined, function() {...});
```

and watcher is usually called once on initialization. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is how you watch the value

```
scope.$watch('currentURL'
```

Second, this is how you're scope def looks like

```
scope : { "currentURL" : '=vcCurrentUrl' }
```

So your directive on the view should be

```
<my-directive data-vc-current-url="vm.data.profileURL"> </my-directive>
```

Comment: first - nope Error: currentURL is not defined if I put what you said
Second is a typo in question - names and views have the same name.  I edited the question

Comment: @Rouz You mean `scope.$watch('"currentURL"'` ?

Comment: this solution will work. mistake was that i put scope.$watch(scope.currentURL ... and not scope.$watch('currentURL'

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
scope.$watch('currentURL', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(' changed to ' + newValue + ' from ' + oldValue);
});
```

You were not referencing the scope variable correctly.

Comment: as I already said to the mate that posted (and deleted) his answer - no this is not right. If I do it i will get this error thrown  Error: currentURL is not defined

Comment: I want to apologize to you and to Alon you were right and I was not. I will post an answer just to describe what I was wrong and how I found it.

Comment: @AlonEitan if you had apostrophes around the name of variable be my guest I will upvote it